# Run Composer with SSH on Shared Hosting with Putty

Tags: php, ssh, composer-php, putty, shared-hosting

I am trying to run Composer with SSH on Shared Hosting with Putty.

So far, the composer directory is on my server above `Public_HTML`.

I have tried the following commands, but nothing happens. It is like it downloaded but didn't install?

```
php composer.phar  
php composer  
$ composer install  
composer update  
composer
```

> Status: 404 Not Found Content-type: text/html
>
> No input file specified.

Please help! =)

Comment: what's the output of these commands?

Comment: I added that just as you was asking. =)

Comment: After which command does it appear?

Comment: php composer.phar  - Which I believe is the best command to install/run it.